# TikZ: Is there concept of layouts in tikz (which I could use in composite pic's)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout

In Qt there is concept of layouts (for example, vertical layout arranges all objects vertically and possibly aligns them, horizontal - arranges horizontally, etc...).

I am trying to solve a problem where layouts would help a lot. Namely, I would like to specify (1) nodes on the left (`{n1}, {n2}, {n3}, {n4}, ...`), (2) text for the center node, (3) nodes on the right. And expect the code to generate multiple nodes that have the following properties:

1. nodes on the left are aligned to the right, and center of *the group* of the nodes is aligned with the center of the center node.
2. the same with right nodes, but mirrored.
3. each node has to be referenc-able outside
4. there should be bounding box with anchors for the entire "thing" to be able to arrange them.

Here is an example of how it could look in latex:

```
\pic (a) [anchor=north] at(0, 0) {                % `a` is the name of entire "thing"
lcrpic={{n1}, {n2}, {n3}, {n4}, {n5}, {n6}, {n7}} % List of nodes on the left
       {Center1:\\many nodes on the left}         % Center node
       {{n1}}                                     % Nodes on the right
   };
```

I **did** manage to make the code below produce the picture below:

```
\pic (a) [anchor=north] at(0, 0) {
   lcrpic={{n1}, {n2}, {n3}, {n4}, {n5}, {n6}, {n7}}   {Center1:\\many nodes on the left}  {{n1}}
};
\pic (b) [anchor=north] at ({$(a-bb.south) - (0cm, 0.4cm)$} -| {$(a-center.south)$}) {
   lcrpic={{111111111111111111111111}}  {Center2:\\Long nodes on the left}  {{11}, {22}, {33}, {44}}
};
\node (f) [nodefx_default] at (-6, -3) {Nodes must be reference-able outside:};
\draw[line width=1pt, draw=red!20] (f) -- (a-leftnodes-node-6);
\draw[line width=1pt, draw=red!20] (f) -- (b-leftnodes-node-1);
```

[image]

## BUT

The code is cumbersome, inefficient and ugly.

##### My question is: what is the right approach in tikz to achieve this?

(Maybe there is something that is similar to layouts in Qt?)

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tikzstyle{noders_default} = [rectangle, rounded corners=8pt, minimum height=17pt, font=\footnotesize, text centered, draw=black!20, thick, fill=white]
   \tikzstyle{nodefx_default} = [noders_default, text width=60pt]

   % ============================== left ==============================

   % the only useful "output" of the pic is "-bb" (invisible) node - it stores geometry of the left part and is used in pics/leftnodes
   \tikzset{
      pics/leftnodeslayout/.style n args = {1}{
         code={
            \begin{scope}[local bounding box = layoutBoundingBox]
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#1} {
                  \ifnum \prevei=0
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, draw=none, opacity=0, text opacity=0] {\elem};
                  \else
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north east, draw=none, opacity=0, text opacity=0] at (-node-\prevei.south east) {\elem};
                  \fi
               }
            \end{scope}
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBox.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBox.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \node[draw=none, green, dashed, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) at (0,0) {};
         }
      }
   }

   % Draw leftnodeslayout => get its "-bb" draw real nodes using "-bb" as reference:
   \tikzset{
      pics/leftnodes/.style n args = {1}{
         code={
            \pic (layout) {leftnodeslayout={#1}};
            \gettikzxy{(layout-bb.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(layout-bb.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \node[draw, green, dashed, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) at (0,0) {};

            \begin{scope}
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#1} {
                  \ifnum \prevei=0
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north east] at (-bb.north east) {\elem};
                  \else
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north east] at (-node-\prevei.south east) {\elem};
                  \fi
               }
            \end{scope}
         }
      }
   }


   % ============================== right ==============================

   % the only useful "output" of the pic is "-bb" (invisible) node - it stores geometry of the right part and is used in pics/righttnodes
   \tikzset{
      pics/rightnodeslayout/.style n args = {1}{
         code={
            \begin{scope}[local bounding box = layoutBoundingBox]
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#1} {
                  \ifnum \prevei=0
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, draw=none, opacity=0, text opacity=0] {\elem};
                  \else
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north east, draw=none, opacity=0, text opacity=0] at (-node-\prevei.south east) {\elem};
                  \fi
               }
            \end{scope}
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBox.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBox.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \node[draw=none, green, dashed, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) at (0,0) {};
         }
      }
   }

   % Draw rightnodeslayout => get its "-bb" draw real nodes using "-bb" as reference:
   \tikzset{
      pics/rightnodes/.style n args = {1}{
         code={
            \pic (layout) {rightnodeslayout={#1}};
            \gettikzxy{(layout-bb.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(layout-bb.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \node[draw, green, dashed, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) at (0,0) {};
            \begin{scope}
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#1} {
                  \ifnum \prevei=0
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north west] at (-bb.north west) {\elem};
                  \else
                     \node (-node-\ei) [noders_default, anchor=north west] at (-node-\prevei.south west) {\elem};
                  \fi
               }
            \end{scope}
         }
      }
   }


   % ============================== LeftCenterRight (lcr) ==============================

   % The same approach here, but for the entire leftnodes-center-rigthnodes:
   \tikzset{
      pics/lcrlayout/.style n args = {3}{
         code={
            \pic (leftnodes) {leftnodeslayout={#1}};
            \gettikzxy{(leftnodes-bb.north west)}{\xLeftL}{\yTopL};
            \gettikzxy{(leftnodes-bb.south east)}{\xRightL}{\yBottomL};

            \pic (rightnodes) {rightnodeslayout={#3}};
            \gettikzxy{(rightnodes-bb.north west)}{\xLeftR}{\yTopR};
            \gettikzxy{(rightnodes-bb.south east)}{\xRightR}{\yBottomR};

            \begin{scope}[local bounding box = layoutBoundingBoxForLCR]
               \node (-center)   [nodefx_default, draw=none, opacity=0, text opacity=0] {#2};
               \node (fakeleftbbrect) [draw=none, anchor=east, left=20pt of -center.west, minimum height=\yTopL - \yBottomL, minimum width=\xRightL - \xLeftL] {};
               \node (fakerightbbrect) [draw=none, anchor=west, right=20pt of -center.east, minimum height=\yTopR - \yBottomR, minimum width=\xRightR - \xLeftR] {};
            \end{scope}
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBoxForLCR.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(layoutBoundingBoxForLCR.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \node[draw=none, green, dashed, anchor=south west, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) at (\xLeft, \yBottom) {};
         }
      }
   }
   \tikzset{
      pics/lcrpic/.style n args = {3}{
         code={
            \pic (-layout) {lcrlayout={{#1}}{#2}{{#3}}};
            \gettikzxy{(-layout-bb.north west)}{\xLeft}{\yTop};
            \gettikzxy{(-layout-bb.south east)}{\xRight}{\yBottom};
            \gettikzxy{(-layout-bb.south)}{\xBbC}{\yBbC};
            \gettikzxy{(-layout-center.south)}{\xC}{\yC};
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\xBbC - \xC]
               \node[draw, blue, dashed, minimum height=\yTop - \yBottom, minimum width=\xRight - \xLeft] (-bb) {};
               \pic (-leftnodes)  [anchor=west] at (-bb.west) {leftnodes={#1}};
               \node (-center)   [nodefx_default, anchor=west, right=20pt of -leftnodes-bb.east] {#2};
               \pic (rightnodes) [anchor=west, right=20pt of -center.east] {rightnodes={#3}};
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#1} {
                  \draw[line width=1pt, draw=black!20] (-center) -- (-leftnodes-node-\ei.east);
               }
               \foreach [count=\ei, remember=\ei as \prevei (initially 0)] \elem in {#3} {
                  \draw[line width=1pt, draw=black!20] (-center) -- (rightnodes-node-\ei.west);
               }
            \end{scope}
         }
      }
   }

   %
   % The interface I want and tests:
   %
   \pic (a) [anchor=north] at(0, 0) {
      lcrpic={{n1}, {n2}, {n3}, {n4}, {n5}, {n6}, {n7}}   {Center1:\\many nodes on the left}  {{n1}}
   };
   \pic (b) [anchor=north] at ({$(a-bb.south) - (0cm, 0.4cm)$} -| {$(a-center.south)$}) {
      lcrpic={{111111111111111111111111}}  {Center2:\\Long nodes on the left}  {{11}, {22}, {33}, {44}}
   };
   \node (f) [nodefx_default] at (-6, -3) {Nodes must be reference-able outside:};
   \draw[line width=1pt, draw=red!20] (f) -- (a-leftnodes-node-6);
   \draw[line width=1pt, draw=red!20] (f) -- (b-leftnodes-node-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may try tikz matrix. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622299) for an example.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ There are also chains and graphs.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, there are matrix, chains and graphs. But they will not give me interface like: input1: "nodes on the left", input2: "center node", input3: "nodes on the right". Output: the picture as in the example. How can I build a **reusable** component with input form/format that I need?